# Google Analytics, jQuery Magnific Popups, .NET master page implementation

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, asp-classic, google-analytics

I will start with admitting that although I have been researching, reading, and trouble-shooting my issue I think I am missing something fundamental with my site.  I apologize for my ignorance in advance but this is the only way to learn--by admitting you don't know what to do.

I'm running a VB.NET site which has a master page and content pages.  I am still very much in development of the entire site trying to add features.

**What I'd like to do:**

I would like to add google analytics and jquery magnific popup.  I've followed all the instructions from google and from magnific pop-up and I'm still having issues.

**What I've done to try and make this work so far:**

*My head on masterpage:*

```
<script src="Scripts/googleanalytics.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*My footer on masterpage:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({type: 'image'});
</script>
```

*Added class to image:*

```
<a class="test-popup-link" href="img/bigdog.jpg"><img class="centerimg" src="img/smalldog.jpg" /></a>
```

*My issues:*

- Google script fails to find script.  It's definitely there, it was
  copy/pasted directly from google's site into a file I am calling.
- jquery and magnific pop-up only load on my root pages.
- "/products/product1.aspx" pages for example refuse to load scripts.
  Although they load on root pages, the script does not appear to work
  for the image pop up.  I've followed magnific-popup's instructions word for word for "initializing in html"

*Instructions for magnific-popup:* http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#mfp-build-tool

Lastly, before I tried adding the image pop-up google analytics appeared to be working as I was getting reporting on the web analytics page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please fix your title to make it relevant to the problem so others having a similar issue in the future can find it.  might save you a few DVs as well.  You **do** want those with relevant expertise to be interested enough to read it, no?

Comment: I've attempted to do an quick fix but if the OP could further improve that, that'd be good.

Comment: Sorry I've adjusted it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found via talking it out on IRC.

I restarted my local server and it worked on my root directory.  Race conditions or caching causing the problem?
I needed to add "/" before "Scripts" in my head which fixed non-root script loading.

Thanks to robert on freenode for talking me through it. :D